# Facebook sdk ShareDialog registerCallback methods not working - Facebook Android SDK

Tags: android, android-facebook

The registerCallback method of ShareDialog is not working. Toast is not being displayed for any of the registerCallback methods. Only the share dialog shows.

Requirement - I want to know if the user has successfully shared the post or discarded it.

```
private void shareRateButtonClickListeners() {
    flFbShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                        .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://androidlift.info"))
                        .build();
                shareDialog.show(getActivity(), linkContent);

            }
        });

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        shareDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Share success!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e(TAG,"Fb onSuccess");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Did not share", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e(TAG,"Fb onCancel");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e(TAG,"Fb onError");
            }
        }, 90);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your activity has implement this function

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Document: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android/